# Regular expression entire string matched not components

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to scan a PHP file for variable definitions e.g. $test="1"; and return both the variable name and the value, here is what I tried so far:

```
preg_match_all('/\$(.*)="(.*)";/', $content, $out);
```

This works fine when I have a lot of variables defined over separate lines, e.g:

```
$test1="1";
$test2="2";
$test3="3";
```

But when the variables are defined one next to another, then my match simply returns one giant string, e.g.

```
$test1="1";$test2="2";$test3="3";
```

I think this is because it is being interpreted as:

```
$test1="[content]";
Where [content] = 1";$test2="2";$test3="3
```

Is there any workaround to this? I need it to FORCE essentially a new match as soon as it encounters "; not simply at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your matches *non greedy*. You can do this by using the quantifier `*?` instead of `*`.

```
$content = '$test1="1";$test2="2";$test3="3";';

$out = array();

preg_match_all('/\$(.*?)="(.*?)";/', $content, $out);

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "$test1="1";"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "$test2="2";"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "$test3="3";"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "test1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "test2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "test3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Greedy expressions such as `.*` will attempt to match as much as possible while satisfying the remaining expression. With each assignment on a separate line (and in the absence of the `/s` [dot-matches-all] modifier), `.*` stops matching at the first encountered newline; this is why it works when the assignments are each on their own line.

The first greedy expression can be modified to use a negative character set instead; the second greedy expression needs to be made non-greedy by appending a question mark (because double quotes may be escaped and you would otherwise need a more complex pattern to take that into account):

```
/\$([^=]*)="(.*?)";/
```

The `[^=]*` will match anything but an equal sign whereas `.*?` will match as soon as possible while satisfying the remaining expression.

Answer (score 0):

Match using `.*?` (lazy quantifier) instead of `.*` (greedy quantifier) to match as soon as possible.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html